# What is he saying in this video

Tags: spoken-english

https://youtu.be/Qg0pO9VG1J8
In the time 0:57 the guy in the strikes shirt is saying Something like HE'S DEFINITELY NOT ...
Can you help me figure out what's he saying

Comment: He says: "He's definitely not PC." before putting a book in the fire place. PC = politically correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELL is not a transcription service

Answer (score 2):

"He's definitely not PC".

*PC* is a relatively new English acronym (in use since the 1990's) that stands for  "Politically Correct".  It means to say or do things in a way to avoid any possible offense.  In most contexts it's a mild insult to imply that the person is so afraid of causing offense to *anyone* that they take this to an unnecessary extreme.

In the context of this ad, when the actor says "Donald Trump is definitely not PC" it means that the speaker likes how Trump speaks his mind and isn't worried about who might be offended by what he says.  This part of the video isn't parody -- there are many in the United States who believe this, and believe it's better to say what you mean than to be so careful of causing offense that you don't actually say things that (they believe) are true.

Of course the video itself is pure satire and goes on to make its point with visual humor that contrasts with what the actors are saying.